# How to read the stdout from the popen() function and store it in the char array in C language?

Tags: c, linux, tcp, posix, popen

Well, I got stuck in sending stdout output to the array. How can I solve this issue? I need to send back the bash command output with the code of execution to the client from the server. The protocol is TCP. Thank you!

```
     void func(int sockfd)
     { 
        char buff[MAX]; 
        for (;;) 
        { 
            bzero(buff, MAX); 
            read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
            printf("From client: %s\n", buff);
            if (strncmp("exit", buff, 4) == 0) 
            { 
                printf("Server Exit...\n"); 
                write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
                break; 
            } 
            FILE *cmd=popen(buff,"r");
            while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), cmd))
            strcpy(buff,cmd);
            pclose(cmd);
            write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
            my_itoa(system(buff),buff);
            write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));          
        } 
     }
```

Comment: Can you please describe what is wrong with your code?

Comment: Okay, when I try to execute the commented part of my code, I don't receive the expected stdout output, like "ls" command to list files on the client side.

Comment: Your commented code does not seem correct. The `while` loop applies to `strcpy` only

Comment: Take a look at the 2nd argument of strcpy() you called. strcpy() has nothing to do with FILE*.

Comment: Then should I convert FILE* to char* type?

Comment: @alimovlex No, you please tell what is your intent to use `strcpy()`

Comment: @Sumit, I need to catch the stdout output and bind it with the socket to send it to the client.

Comment: @JohnPark Should I convert FILE* to char* type in order to use strcpy?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't receive the expected stdout output, like "ls" command to list files on the client side.

Comment: @alimovlex, No, you should NOT do that. You can write back to the sockfd the characters you read in the while loop. Simply add write code in the loop and get rid of strcpy() there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to send back to the client your execution result of bash command. You can change your code to write to sockfd every time you get a line of characters from cmd.

```
FILE* cmd=popen(buff, "r");
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), cmd))
{
  write(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff));  // sizeof() will write more than you actually read.
}
pclose(cmd);
```

Comment: And probably below also in addition to above(except last line pclose without return value):

`   int ret = pclose(cmd); //return value of command, dont do system() again
    my_itoa(ret, buff); //OR, sprintf(buff, "%d", ret);
    write(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff));`